# Check @RequestMapping - unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-mvc, tdd

I have a task to do:
This controller should have its own unit test to verify, that `@RequestMapping` is set to `/ api / report / article_pairs`.

```
 @RestController
 @RequestMapping("/api/report/article_pairs")
 public class ArticlePairsController extends ReportController<ArticlePairs>{

public ArticlePairsController(HttpReportExecutor<ArticlePairs> articlePairs) {
    super(articlePairs);
}

@PostMapping()
public HttpEntity<Void> proceed(@RequestBody ArticlePairs articlePairs) {

    articlePairs.setDbconn(schemaName + "." + CENTRALA);

    return executeReport(articlePairs, "report.articlePairs");
  }
}
```

If someone in the future would change this value, a unit test should show this.

Unit testing is a new issue for me, so could I ask for some advice? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have not stated which version of Spring you are using, but if it is greater than 3.2 you could set up a simple unit test that ONLY tests a given Controller and not the whole context as follows:

```
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class SitemapControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(SitemapControllerTest.class).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testHappyPath() throws Exception {

        mvc.perform(post("/api/report/article_pairs")
                .content("{yourjsoncontent}")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, but could  you tell me what 'myjsoncontent' is and where can I find it?

Comment: It is the json representation of ArticlePairs